# What are the conditions to make the embedded C code written for one processor to work on another processor (when architecture is same)?

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I am reading a primer text on embedded C programming (it is: [Barr & Massa, 2007](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009836)). For companion hardware board to run examples, they recommend [Arcom VIPER-Lite](http://arcom.industrialpartner.com/embedded-boards/pc104-compatible-processor-boards/viper-lite.htm). But I do already have Beaglebone Black (BBB) board and I don't want to buy a new board.

The two boards have same architecture, namely, ARM but BBB uses TI AM3358BZCZ100 processor, clocked at 1GHz, whereas VIPER-Lite uses Intel's PXA255 processor, clocked at 200MHz. The BBB board has more memory and basically more of everything.

My question is, can I follow and execute embedded C code examples given in this book on my BBB board? Does embedded C code depend on processors or architecture or something else? I understand that very specific examples addressing particular peripherals/drivers may not be portable from one platform to next but is entire embedded code like this? I am hope I am making sense.

Comment: As long as the code in the book doesn't use any hardware specific things that exists on the VIPER-Lite board that doesn't exist on the BBB, or uses timings tied to the clock frequency, then it's okay. The problem comes when the code tries to access hardware directly, because that most likely won't be the same.

Comment: From a scan of the Amazon preview, I wouldn't hold out too much hope - the majority of the examples sound like bare-metal stuff which is going to be entirely platform-specific. If the explanatory chapters are sufficiently general they might still be a useful read (which some of the reviews seem to imply), but I'd probably consider the practical elements a write-off. 10 years is an awfully long time in this corner of technology (and the less said about using GCC 3.4 the better) - rather than buying a new board, I'd consider a buying a new book...

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks. I have thought of newer book as 2007 is really too far back in this technology but I like this book and writers' style (at least from first 1.5 chapters... I am reading it right now). Could you please suggest a newer book covering similar material?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can be much help there - the closest thing I own to an "embedded programming" book would probably be [this](https://www.amazon.com/Assembler-IBM-PC-XT/dp/0835901106/ref=tmm_pap_title_2?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=), which also does not translate well to other platforms ;)

Answer (score 3):

Intel X-Scale is not the same as Cortex-A8 - ARM architecture has been through a number of versions since then, and Intel implemented some proprietary features too.  Moreover ARM licencees are free to implement proprietary peripheral sets and subsets of the core architecture.

In particular for board bring-up the PLL and SDRAM controller will be entirely different between different vendor's devices and even between different generations of device from the same vendor.

If you are running code on an already implemented OS (BeagleBone is delivered with Linux already installed), then you will not need to worry about board bring up and peripheral support; but you will also miss out in learning a great deal about embedded systems (other than perhaps embedded systems that run pre-installed or vendor supplied Linux distros, which is a small subset or all embedded systems).

Beyond board bring up the boards will have entirely different peripheral sets, different on-board devices, and differing I/O at different addresses and with different register sets - no code that directly accesses the I/O is will work.  Code accessing devices through a standard Linus device driver interface may well work because an abstraction to a common interface is provided by the OS and board vendor or third party device drivers.

If you are not running the code on Linux - or are implementing low-level device drivers, then the programming environment in terms of memory map, MMU, PLL, I/O control, peripherals, and even instruction set will be different and any code will require adaptation, and you will need to get familiar with the corresponding data sheets or reference manuals and also the ARM technical reference.

So the answer is that it depends largely on where you are starting from; bare-metal or Linux.

There are resources related to "bare-metal" development on BeagleBone Black in particular TI's own bare-metal [StarterWare](http://www.ti.com/tool/starterware-sitara) library.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you learn from most good text books can be applied any microprocessor or micro controller at a very high level. But if you want learn embedded system programming using Beagle Bone Black I suggest the following youtube links from Prof Derek Molloy. Prof Molloy does a fantastic job of teaching embedded System programming using BBB. Here are few links for you to get started.

- [The Beaglebone - Unboxing, Introduction Tutorial and First Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6b4zlh0IrE)
- [Beaglebone: C/C++ Programming Introduction for ARM Embedded Linux Development using Eclipse CDT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFv_-ykLppo&index=2&list=PLF4A1A7E09E5E260A)
- [Beaglebone: GPIO Programming on ARM Embedded Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaIpz00lE84&index=3&list=PLF4A1A7E09E5E260A)

The one problem you might want to be aware is that the video were based on  Angstrom Distribution. The current BBB is shipped with Debian Distribution.

Also if you want to learn bare-metal embedded system program you might want check out

- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-03x)

You might also want to take look at the following link for more material.

- [Beginning with programming microcontrollers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/192225/50587)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The xscale although ARM instruction set derived is not ARM in the sense that you want to use it.  For some reason the native mode is big endian and normal ARM native mode is little endian.  But more important the core processor is not insignificant, but not the bulk if the porting effort, most of not all of the peripherals are expected to differ between those two chips, most of the code would need a re-write unless it is a purely portable C program that runs on any say linux, then arm, xscale, x86 are completely irrelevant to the discussion.  I suspect you are not in that situation.  Even compiled as a generic command line linux app would still have problems in this situation with the endianness.

Basically you are saying I have two fords and I want to take the wheels off of one and put them on the other, without understanding that one is a ford festiva and the other is lets say an F350 pickup.  Just because they have the same looking tiny ford badge on them, doesnt mean that the entirety of their components are identical.

If you are desperate to re-use these binaries, you are better off finding or making a simulator for the prior platform and then you can run that on anything.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination.